# How to choose training data from a satellite imagery for supervised classification?

Tags: image-processing, classification, random-forest, training-data, satellite-image

I am performing supervised classification of Sentinel 2 imagery using a Random Forest Classifier. I wish to select the training data from the image. Could anyone please tell me the method to efficiently perform this?